# Setting _id field to ObjectId in MongoDB before it is written to DB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have some tags on a post that I want to search against at a later time. The tags are all in a different collection and I add their `_id` and some other data to an `array` on each post object. However, when the post is written all the tag ID's are put in as `strings` rather than `ObjectId's` which causes a problem because they don't match later down the line when I'm searching against them. My question is how do I get them to be put into the DB with `ObjectId` when they are initially added to the DB? I don't think I can convert them later when searching since I am using `$lookup` for searching.

Here is an example of how they are currently being written to the DB:

```
// Other post data...
"tags" : [
    {
        "_id" : "5c69d914e05511106048780c",
        "name" : "Food",
        "createdAt" : "2019-02-17T21:58:44.869Z",
        "updatedAt" : "2019-02-17T21:58:44.869Z",
        "__v" : 0
    },
    ...
];
```

My initial idea was to do something like this when creating a new post:

```
const tmpTools = [tools here];

tmpTools.forEach(function(tool) {
    console.log(ObjectId(tool._id));
});

// Then add the post to the collection
```

**Update: Here is what my schema looks like using mongoose**

```
const postSchema = new Schema({
    title: { type: String, required: true },
    body: { type: String, required: true },
    tags: { type: Array, required: true },
    author_id: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User', required: true },
    author_name: { type: String, required: true },
    likes_count: { type: Number, required: true },
    dislikes_count: { type: Number, required: true },
    status: { type: String, required: true },
},
    { timestamps: true }
);
```

**Edit: After adding a post I am using the aggregation framework to find how many times a tag is being used by posts**

```
Tag.aggregate([ 
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: 'recipes',
            localField: '_id',
            foreignField: 'tags._id',
            as: 'posts'
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: You tagged your question with "mongoose". If your schema is set correctly then it does this for you. What does your schema look like? Or is this just a theoretical question and you have not yet tried submitting strings and seen them *"autocast"* for you? `_id` ( in sub-document arrays ) is generally automatically handled unless you set `{ _id: false }` in the options.

Comment: @NeilLunn I added my schema

Comment: So All you have is `tags: { type: Array }` instead you should have defined the schema separately and used it with something like `tags: [tagsSchema]`. Then things autocast. See [Subdocuments](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html) in the documentation for an example

Comment: @NeilLunn Gives me this error: `TypeError: Invalid schema configuration: `model` is not a valid type within the array `tags`.See URL HERE for a list of valid schema types.`

Comment: Please actually look at the linked documentation page as it is a very clear example. You don't need to assign `mongoose.model(...)` to a sub-document, since it's not a "collection".

Comment: @NeilLunn That does technically work but since it's not a model then I can't use aggregate later on the tags. I've updated the post to show what I was doing later down the line. Also tags is a collection, not sure if that's what you meant?

Comment: You should really [Ask a New Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) as things like "aggregation down the line" are not really related to the original question, nor is your statement remotely correct. People aggregate embedded arrays or referenced data all of the time, and this site is full of questions doing just that.

Comment: @NeilLunn Actually it is related. I had already asked a different which you marked as a duplicate. After looking at the other question it seemed that this was my issue, so I asked this question. I appreciate your willingness to help but since I am obviously new to this perhaps some further guidance would be nice.

Comment: [This is the marked duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54982681/2313887) and the reason is because `_id` in the arrays is a "string". The answer that is shown actually shows you how to convert your data from "string" to `ObjectId` or otherwise handling the problem by using a "view". **This Question** you are asking shows your schema is defined incorrectly. So you have "two" things to do. 1. Fix the schema so that new items assign `_id` correctly. 2. Fix your existing data, just like the very helpful answer already showed you. Neither `$lookup` or `populate()` will work until `2` is done